# Showing the equation $Ax=b$ is well posed if $x$ is least squares solution of minimal norm

Tags: normed-spaces, matrix-equations, least-squares, inverse-problems

> The operator equation $Tf=g$ is said to be totally well-posed where $T:H_1\to H_2$ if for each $g\in H_2$.(H_1 and H_2 are Hilbert spaces.)
>
> The equation has a unique solution and this solution depends continuously on both the "data" $g$ and the "model" operator $T$.

It's clear to me that when $A$ is invertible, the equation $Ax=b$ is totally well-posed. However, I have no idea why if we replace the notion of "solution" by "least squares solution of minimal norm", the matrix equation is only well-posed.(Not totally well-posed). I appreciate any hint.

Comment: The least squares solution of minimal norm is unique but it does not depend continuously on $A$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Can you explain why it doesn't depend continuously on $A$. If the matrix equation $Ax=b$ has infinitely solution, isn't the least squares solution be  equal to $A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$? I may be wrong.

Comment: That expression only makes sense if $AA^T$ is invertible. In general, it's given by multiplying $b$ by something called the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, which can depend discontinuously on $A$ if the rank of $A$ changes.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Why don't you write it as a full answer?

Answer (score -1):

Given $\mathcal{A} \in\mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$, the linear system
$$
 \mathbf{A} x = b
$$
we have existence of a least squares solution when $b\notin\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{A}^{*})$. The least squares minimizers are
$$
  x_{LS} = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b + \left( \mathbf{I}_{n} - \mathbf{A}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A}\right) z, \quad z \in \mathbb{C}^{n}.
$$
The minimizers are an affine space, represented by the dashed red line in the figure below.

[image: Domain]

When $\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}\right)$ is trivial, the least squares solution is
$$
 x_{LS} = \mathbf{A}^{\dagger} b = \left( \mathbf{A}^{*} \mathbf{A} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{A}^{*} b.
$$
When  the nullspace is trivial, $\mathcal{N}\left( \mathbf{A}\right) = \mathbf{0}$, and $\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} \mathbf{A} = \mathbf{I}_{n}$, and the least squares solution is unique. (Fredholm alternative.)

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's question.